# How can I check if a div has an image and disable/enable a button

Tags: jquery

I have some empty divs with a class of 'pick' that allow images to be dropped flawlessly.  Each time an image is dropped I want to have a button that becomes enabled from its initial state of 'disabled'.  I have looked at many examples of this kind of functionality for input fields but not for images being dropped.  The logic seems fine to me I am just stumped.

**JQUERY:**

```
var empty = false;
    $('.pick').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("img").length == 0) {

            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<input type="submit" id="button" disabled='disabled' />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post some context? The logic here seems to be fine, but a JSFiddle would really help. Mostly, I want to see the 'dropping' logic for images.

Comment: By dropped, do you mean HTML5 [Drag and Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)? This does not actually add an `<img>` element to the page...

Comment: Oh no I am aware...I am not having any trouble with the actual drag and drop functionality.  Like I said I have that running perfectly  It is just the button being enabled/disabled when an image is inside of my divs

Comment: does the jquery executes each time an image is dropped? with that code it will just run once when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the drop event, and enable the button on drop

```
$('.pick').on('drop', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) { // file added
            $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     }
});
```

Note that this only works for one single button as ID's are unique

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qph5B/)